# Python - How to split cell in a column to a new row based of a delmimeter

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Relatively new and trying to split some data with python from a CSV file. I am trying to parse this data and split it into a new row if a specific delimiter appears. Those delimiters are  '.'  ';'  and '#'.  There are also no spaces in COL_C.  In addition, it wouldn't matter the order of the delimiters, if we find one of them, automatically create the new line.

Here is the example data

`COL_A | COL_B |COL_C`
`--------------------`
`Hello | World | Hi.Can;You#Help`

the output i'm trying to get would be:

`COL_A | COL_B | COL_C`
`----------------------`
`Hello | World | Hi`
`Hello | World | Can`
`Hello | World | You`
`Hello | World | Help`

example 2:

`COL_A | COL_B | COL_C`
`----------------------`
`Hello | World | Hi#123;move`
`New   | line  | Can.I#parse;this.data`

the output i'm trying to get would be:

`COL_A | COL_B | COL_C`
`----------------------`
`Hello | World | Hi`
`Hello | World | 123`
`Hello | World | move`
`New   | Line  | Can`
`New   | Line  | I`
`New   | Line  | parse`
`New   | Line  | this`
`New   | Line  | data`

If this data set had another row without Hello World and had world hello in the first two columns, i would like to display that with the corresponding third column's data parsed out into new rows.

thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Blend of Speed and Elegance***

```
def pir(df, c):
    colc = df[c].str.split('\.|;|#')
    clst = colc.values.tolist()
    lens = [len(l) for l in clst]

    cdf = pd.DataFrame({c: np.concatenate(clst)}, df.index.repeat(lens))
    return df.drop(c, 1).join(cdf).reset_index(drop=True)
```

***Forget Elegance, Give me Speed!***

```
def pir2(df, c):
    colc = df[c].str.split('\.|;|#')
    clst = colc.values.tolist()
    lens = [len(l) for l in clst]
    j = df.columns.get_loc(c)
    v = df.values
    n, m = v.shape
    r = np.arange(n).repeat(lens)
    return pd.DataFrame(
        np.column_stack([v[r, 0:j], np.concatenate(clst), v[r, j+1:]]),
        columns=df.columns
    )
```

---

```
pir(df, 'COL_C')
# pir2(df, 'COL_C')

   COL_A  COL_B  COL_C
0  Hello  World     Hi
1  Hello  World    123
2  Hello  World   move
3    New   line    Can
4    New   line      I
5    New   line  parse
6    New   line   this
7    New   line   data
```

---

***Timing***

```
%timeit pir(df, 'COL_C')
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.42 ms per loop

%timeit pir2(df, 'COL_C')
1000 loops, best of 3: 278 µs per loop

%timeit split_list_in_cols_to_rows(df.assign(COL_C=df.COL_C.str.split(r'[.,;#]')), lst_cols='COL_C')
100 loops, best of 3: 4.16 ms per loop

%%timeit 
COL_C2 = df.COL_C.str.split('\.|;|#').apply(pd.Series).stack()
df.drop('COL_C', 1).join(pd.Series(index=COL_C2.index.droplevel(1), data=COL_C2.values, name='COL_C')).reset_index(drop=True)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.81 ms per loop
```

***Setup***

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

txt = """COL_A | COL_B | COL_C
Hello | World | Hi#123;move
New   | line  | Can.I#parse;this.data """

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(txt), sep='\s*\|\s*', engine='python')
```

Comment: This assumes that *all* entries in `COL_C` have to be split. If this is correct, what if that's not the case?

Comment: I will try to split it but if it can't it will just take the single row.

Answer (score 5):

**Setup**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'COL_A': {0: 'Hello ', 1: 'New   '},
 'COL_B': {0: ' World ', 1: ' line  '},
 'COL_C': {0: ' Hi#123;move', 1: ' Can.I#parse;this.data '}})
Out[480]: 
    COL_A    COL_B                    COL_C
0  Hello    World               Hi#123;move
1  New      line     Can.I#parse;this.data
```

**Solution**

```
#split COL_C by given delimeter and stack them up in a series
COL_C2 = df.COL_C.str.split('\.|;|#',expand=True).stack()
#join the new series (after setting a name and index) back to the dataframe
df.join(pd.Series(index=COL_C2.index.droplevel(1), data=COL_C2.values, name='COL_C2'))

Out[475]: 
    COL_A    COL_B                    COL_C COL_C2
0  Hello    World               Hi#123;move     Hi
0  Hello    World               Hi#123;move    123
0  Hello    World               Hi#123;move   move
1  New      line     Can.I#parse;this.data     Can
1  New      line     Can.I#parse;this.data       I
1  New      line     Can.I#parse;this.data   parse
1  New      line     Can.I#parse;this.data    this
1  New      line     Can.I#parse;this.data   data
```

Comment: Thanks @piRSquared for the suggestion to use expand.

Answer (score 2):

**example 1**

```
In [107]: df
Out[107]:
   COL_A  COL_B            COL_C
0  Hello  World  Hi.Can;You#Help
```

**Solution:**

```
def split_list_in_cols_to_rows(df, lst_cols, fill_value=''):
    # make sure `lst_cols` is a list
    if lst_cols and not isinstance(lst_cols, list):
        lst_cols = [lst_cols]
    # all columns except `lst_cols`
    idx_cols = df.columns.difference(lst_cols)

    # calculate lengths of lists
    lens = df[lst_cols[0]].str.len()

    return pd.DataFrame({
        col:np.repeat(df[col].values, df[lst_cols[0]].str.len())
        for col in idx_cols
    }).assign(**{col:np.concatenate(df[col].values) for col in lst_cols}) \
      .append(df.loc[lens==0, idx_cols]).fillna(fill_value) \
      .loc[:, df.columns]

In [106]: split_list_in_cols_to_rows(df.assign(COL_C=df.COL_C.str.split(r'[.,;#]')),
                                     lst_cols='COL_C')
Out[106]:
   COL_A  COL_B COL_C
0  Hello  World    Hi
1  Hello  World   Can
2  Hello  World   You
3  Hello  World  Help
```

**example 2:**

```
In [110]: df
Out[110]:
   COL_A  COL_B                  COL_C
0  Hello  World            Hi#123;move
1    New   line  Can.I#parse;this.data

In [111]: split_list_in_cols_to_rows(df.assign(COL_C=df.COL_C.str.split(r'[.,;#]')),
     ...:                                      lst_cols='COL_C')
Out[111]:
   COL_A  COL_B  COL_C
0  Hello  World     Hi
1  Hello  World    123
2  Hello  World   move
3    New   line    Can
4    New   line      I
5    New   line  parse
6    New   line   this
7    New   line   data
```

Comment: Very nice solution. However, my dataframe, which has `columns=[From, To]` and has only `;` as a separator in the `To` column, when processed returns this error: `Cannot cast array data from dtype('float64') to dtype('int64') according to the rule 'safe'`. This points at `for col in idx_cols
     }).assign(**{col:np.concatenate(df[col].values) for col in lst_cols}).append(df.loc[lens==0, idx_cols]).fillna(fill_value).loc[:, df.columns]`.