# Using character value to create new rows in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, split, fill

I need to create new rows in a `pandas` dataframe based on a value that occurs in a specific column.

The pattern to create the Split is that there is a semi colon that indicates where I need to initiate a new row.

df

```
animal  cat;dog;cat
animal  dog
animal  fish
color   black;green
color   red
```

desired_df

```
animal  cat
animal  dog
animal  cat
animal  dog
animal  fish
color   black
color green
color   red
```

I have seen solutions that use pandas split to create new columns or rows using a given character or values in the df (such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47394793/pandas-split-a-dataframe-rows-and-re-arrange-column-values): and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44878959/split-row-into-multiple-rows-in-pandas): ), however, I have not seen a solution that does this with text values. I have also seen solutions (as well as one that I requested myself [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50965844/using-boolean-logic-to-clean-df-in-pandas/50966169#50966169)) that is able to accurately fill in the null values in pandas. However, I need to combine these two techniques and it is not clear to me if this is feasible to do in a one-liner (or two).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43794429/python-how-to-split-cell-in-a-column-to-a-new-row-based-of-a-delmimeter
Check the solutions there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [200]: df
Out[200]:
     col1         col2
0  animal  cat;dog;cat
1  animal          dog
2  animal         fish
3   color  black;green
4   color          red

In [201]: (df.set_index('col1')
             .col2.str.split(';', expand=True)
             .stack()
             .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
             .reset_index(name='col2'))
Out[201]:
     col1   col2
0  animal    cat
1  animal    dog
2  animal    cat
3  animal    dog
4  animal   fish
5   color  black
6   color  green
7   color    red
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `numpy.repeat` and `itertools.chain`:

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import chain

split = df['col2'].str.split(';')

res = pd.DataFrame({'col1': np.repeat(df['col1'], split.map(len)),
                    'col2': list(chain.from_iterable(split))})

print(res)

     col1   col2
0  animal    cat
0  animal    dog
0  animal    cat
1  animal    dog
2  animal   fish
3   color  black
3   color  green
4   color    red
```